# take minutes only from the time format in php before the record update

Tags: php

`$aak` is show `00:17:00`   and i just want get 17

```
$aak=$data2["jamwaktukerja"];
```

i use this code for get minute,but still wrong

```
$time = date("i ", $aak);

var_dump($time);    


$masuk2 = 'UPDATE presensi SET menitwaktukerja ="'.$time.'"  where 
tanggal="'.$cellValueB.'" and  nip="'.$data1["nip"].'" ';
$query4 = mysqli_query($con,$masuk2);
```

Comment: you need to provide `date` with a valid timestamp as second parameter. `00:17:00` is not a timestamp yet.You can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for that.

Comment: If you are 100% sure, that the input is always in this format you could `$time = explode(':', $aak)` and you'll have the minutes in `$time[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get the minutes of that input string.

Using explode - use only if the input is always the same format:

```
<?php

$aak = "00:17:00";

$time = explode(':', $aak);
$minutes = $time[1];

echo $minutes;  // 17
```

Using DateTime Class:

```
$aak = "00:17:00";
// either with specified format:
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s",$aak);
// or without:
$d = new DateTime($aak);
$minutes = $d->format("i");
echo $minutes;  // 17

// as a oneliner:

$minutes = (new DateTime($aak))->format("i");
```

Go the way you did, via date(), but provide it with a valid timestamp created with strtotime():

```
$aak = "00:17:00";
$timestamp = strtotime($aak);
$minutes = date("i", $timestamp);
echo $minutes;  // 17
```